# LIKE operator MySQL doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, search, utf-8, sql-like

I tried to make search using LIKE operator:

```
SELECT author_id, header, text FROM blog_u.posts WHERE text LIKE '%Samsung%';
```

It works with latin symbols but doesn't work with russian

```
SELECT author_id, header, text FROM blog_u.posts WHERE text LIKE '%Проверка%';
```

My database in utf-8. Help me pls

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Appears to be working for me in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49cc2/1

Comment: My problem has been in my Servlet encoding, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow-up to my comment, I don't think you're having an issue with `LIKE`.  However, you have to make sure what you're searching for have the equivalent ascii values.

For example, consider this:

```
select * from posts where Text Like '%Проверка%';
select ascii('p');
select ascii('р');
```

The 'p' looks identical in both, but the ascii version is indeed different -- one works, and the other doesn't.  I copied the p in your above statement vs. just typing a p on my keyboard.

[Here is a Fiddle to demonstrate.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49cc2/4)